# ffmpeg H264 mp4 and AVCHD avc1 vs HDPR?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I am running the following command to get the stream data for mp4 and AVCHD video files. My goal is to understand the differences if any between the video streams. I used a JVC camcorder for the test.

```
ffmpeg -i file.mts
ffmpeg -i file.mp4
```

The result command displayed the following for video streams regarding h264 for the MTS and MP4 files.

```
h264 (high) (HDPR / 0x332D4341)
h264 (high) (avc1 / 0x31637661)
```

I gather that the `(high)` is the h264 profile. What is the HDPR and hex number that follows? The above output is from the MTS and MP4 files respectively. I have searched the ITU's document on h264 and did not find references to avc1 nor HDPR.

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: Those are codec tags. Many apps rely on these to decide which decoder to employ. If the tag isn't recognised,  the video won't show even if the app is otherwise capable of working with it

Comment: Avc1 is standard.  HDPR looks proprietary